# How do their batteries get changed?

Tags: chappie

Towards the end of the movie [Chappie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1823672/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) we see:

> Chappie and Deon are transferred into new mechanical bodies.

One of the key premises of the movie is that

> Chappie's battery is fused with his titanium body and not able to be changed, thus he only has a five day lifespan.

After the switch towards the end:

> How do Chappie, Deon, and ultimately Momma get their batteries replaced or recharged?

Comment: Given that, unlike Chappie's original body, they do not have severe damage to their torsos, I think we can assume that their batteries are not fused to their bodies. They would use whatever process was initially used to replace or recharge the batteries of the other Scouts.

Comment: It sounded in the movie as though replacement was the means by which they did it. If so, where would they get the supply of batteries? Is there anything in the context of the movie or written which specifies how they continued to be charged after the fact?

Comment: Considering that they've hacked enough access to Tetravaal that they _built Yolandi's new robot body there_, it seems that it would be trivial to bring some batteries and a charger home with her.

Comment: I was hoping there was something definitive in universe which talked about it, or maybe through writer/directoral interview, or maybe in book form. I know they didn't talk about it in the movie. I can make the same supposition you are making right now (in fact I have).